# Run external application from SharePoint under user credentials

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've got the following problem: I have to call and external program through SharePoint and return to the UI the response of this external program. So, I'm using `Named pipes` to accomplish this:

```
 var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
 startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
 startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 startInfo.FileName = "my.exe";
 Process.Start(startInfo);

 var response = string.Empty;
 using (var pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream("test_pipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message))
 {
        pipe.WaitForConnection();

        byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Who run this?");
        pipe.Write(message, 0, message.Length);

        response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ReadMessage(pipe));
 }
```

The external program should perform it's logic taking in account a user who triggered it through SharePoint:

```
using (var pipe = new NamedPipeClientStream("test_pipe"))
{
       pipe.Connect();
       pipe.ReadMode = PipeTransmissionMode.Message;

       var whoDoneIt = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; // if it's called through SharePoint it'll be service account
       // perform some logic
       pipe.Write(response, 0, response.Length);
}
```

But it appears that it's launched by service account. I mean, if I call this external program using, for example, console app, `whoDoneIt` variable captures correct username (in this case mine) and as a result external app return correct response. Is there any possibility to overcome this obstacle in SharePoint?

Comment: From where you launch the application inside Sharepoint ? WebPart ?

Comment: @Max from HttpHandler (I'm using .ashx file for this purpose)

Comment: I think is not possible, NamedPipe don't expose Credentials.